# Vagrant port forwarding not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows, vagrant, vmware, nat, portforwarding

I am using `Vagrant 1.7.2` and `VMware Workstation 11.1.2` with the plugin `vagrant-vmware-workstation 3.2.9`. My host is Windows 8 and my guest is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (though I have tried multiple different guest boxes).

I followed the getting started directions exactly, which means I now have a Vagrantfile that looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
end
```

And bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y curl
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

The box starts up with no problems and I can connect to it via `vagrant ssh` and confirm everything is working right from within the guest. When it starts up, the ports seem to be forwarding correctly:

```
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
==> default: Preparing network adapters...
==> default: Starting the VMware VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 192.168.131.128:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: -- 80 => 4567
    default: -- 22 => 2222
==> default: Configuring network adapters within the VM...
==> default: Waiting for HGFS kernel module to load...
==> default: Enabling and configuring shared folders...
    default: -- C:/Vhosts/vagrant_getting_started: /vagrant
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I can browse to `http://192.168.131.128/` from my host machine and see the directory index. However, when I try to browse to `http://localhost:4567/` I get a blank page with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

From the guest, `curl -v 'http://localhost:80/'` gives me the expected 200 OK response and html.

From the host, `curl -v 'http://localhost:4567/'` gives me connection refused:

```
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to ::1 port 4567 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4567 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
```

I have found many posts that say to check the curl results, but none that indicate what to do if it isn't right.

**Random stuff I have tried to get it working:**

- Changed the port being forwarded.
- Added `auto_correct: true` to my forwarded port.
- Disabled Windows Firewall.
- Checked iptables (command not found).
- Provisioned the guest multiple times.
- Changed which box I am using.
- Removed all boxes and downloaded fresh.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled each plugin.
- Completely removed Vagrant and VMware and reinstalled.
- Googled like crazy.

**Update**
I manually added port forwarding in VMware workstation from Edit > Virtual Network Editor > NAT. This worked as desired and I can view the directory listing at `http://localhost:4567/` now. However, I don't want to have to manually do this every time I make a new machine, or a machine's IP address changes. I want to manage port forwarding from vagrant only as I will be version controlling this project.

**Update x2**
Setting the port forwarding in VMware isn't a viable solution. The next time the box is reloaded, Vagrant complains about port collision since it is already 'in use.'

**Update x3: PROGRESS!**
I ran vagrant up --debug and looked closely at the port forwarding section. I noticed it was writing to the Windows NAT configuration file and found where that file is located. The forwarded port (now `8080`) is mentioned nowhere in the debug output nor in the file itself. If I add the port forwarding manually, it does appear in the file. Here is a difference between the two: https://www.diffchecker.com/qoazuggp

Now the big question... **why aren't the forwarded ports in the string saved to the NAT config?**

The frustrating thing: it worked originally. Something *changed* on my host machine and I don't know what. I provisioned two vms after the first one. One machine was created with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) default settings, the other machine was included with [zf-apigility-skeleton](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton). I noticed port forwarding stopped working after that, but completely removing everything and starting over hasn't fixed it.

Comment: What I don't get is why Vagrant configure itself with `http://192.168.131.128/` ip. Localhost resolves to `127.0.0.1`, then is it logical I guess that you don't get a response. Buy why the other ip? When I do `vagrant up`, I get the same but with the localhost official ip: 
    `default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key`

Comment: That IP is its address on the private network - because as far as your computer is concerned the vm is another physical machine. Port forwarding says, "Okay, if I receive a request on port `4567`, I should forward that request to the other machine located at `192.168.131.128` on port `80`." Except in my case, its not actually doing the forward, its trying to access 4567 on my host machine, which is refused.

Comment: Yes, but what I was trying to say, is that putting `http://localhost:4567` on your host browser is the same as putting `https://127.0.0.1:4567`. And since your VM is in that other IP, it's logical it can't access it. Try this on your Vagrantfile: `config.ssh.host = 127.0.0.1` (see here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html). If not configured, the provider does it for you, and it is putting that other ip that doesn't allow you to use localhost from your host. Unless I understood everything wrong concerning port-forwarding...

Comment: Yes, `localhost:4567` is the same as `127.0.0.1:4567`. In both cases it is sending a request to the host machine. The host machine has the port forwarding rules; it is supposed to forward the request to the other IP address based on those rules. It SHOULD be able to access the other address... that is the point of port forwarding.